# Laravel 5.5; Duplicate entry on 3-way pivot table with 3 composite primary key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to attach data to my 3-way pivot table (consisting of a user_id, respondent_id and company_id which together is the composite primary key).

When the data already exists in the table I get an duplicate key message (duh)

I tried to prevent this by using syncWithoutDetaching but it still throws a duplicate key message

What I tried to do is the following:

```
class Respondent extends Authenticatable
{
    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Company', 'company_user_respondent');
    }
    public function attachPivot($company_id, $user_id)
    {
        //This will attach but if the keys exist it will send a duplication error
        return $this->companies()->attach($company_id, ['user_id' => $user_id]);
    }
}
```

Furthermore I tried this with the attachPivot method

```
public function attachPivot($company_id, $guide_id)
{
    //Will allso send a duplication error, using just sync works but of course it will clean up my table which is not the goal.
    return $this->companies()->syncWithoutDetaching([1 => ['company_id' => $company_id, 'guide_id' => $guide_id]]);
}
```

I could check my DB if the record exists but doing a query everytime is not my desirable goal, my desirable goal is that no record would be inserted without throwing an error or to sync the table without detaching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that I could prevent this by doing the following

```
try {
    return $this->companies()->attach($company_id, ['user_id' => $user_id]);
} catch (QueryException $exception) {
    return $exception;
}
```

Now it will return either an exception which I can check or attach the specified values.